# Wired mouse and other peripherals works except for ANY wired keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse

I'm using a PS/2 Keyboard and funny as it sounds any USB keyboard is try wont work. I tried freshly reformat OS (WIN7). I even bought i new motherboard hoping that this will fix the problem but nope. How come it's only affecting the USB keyboards. Mouse and flash drives i plug in works perfectly fine.

I also tried removing all devices that is currently plugged in and left the keyboard the only one plugged in. Still the same

**EDIT 1:**

Keyboard "works" But its super delayed. You have to press multiple times till the letter comes out

**EDIT 2:**

I tried using a PS/2 -> USB Adapter and plug two of my USB keyboards in there. It was improved but it's still lagging. It reduced the lag but some keys would still be missed when i try to type in a normal speed